# How to pass method as function with parameters?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm using `spring-webflux` to call an external webservice async, like:

```
String param1;
int param2;

webClient.send(...)
          .exchange()
          .doOnSuccess(rsp -> processResponse(rsp))
          .onErrorMap(ex -> processException(ex, param1, param2));
```

Now I want to refactor the actual sending into a more generic method, and the caller should provide the success + error functions a parameters. But how?

```
public Mono send(Function success, Function error) {
    return webClient.send(...)
              .exchange()
              .doOnSuccess(success)
              .onErrorMap(error);
}
```

Question: how can I now pass the functions to my generic method?

It must be similar to the following pseudo code, but how exactly do I have to write the functions?

```
public void caller() {
     String param1;
     int param2;

     send(
            rsp -> processResponse(rsp),
            ex -> processException(ex, param1, param2)
     );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you definitely want to use `onErrorMap()` (to map one exception to another) then:

```
public Mono<ClientResponse> send(Consumer<? super ClientResponse> success, Function<? super Throwable, ? extends Throwable> error) {
  return webClient()
      .get()
      .uri("http://example.com/")
      .exchange()
      .doOnSuccess(success)
      .onErrorMap(error);
}

send(cr -> processResponse(cr), ex -> mapToAnotherException(ex));
```

...but it sounds like you want to actually add a side-effect on an error, which would be `doOnError()` instead:

```
public Mono<ClientResponse> send(Consumer<? super ClientResponse> success, Consumer<? super Throwable> error) {
  return webClient()
      .get()
      .uri("http://example.com/")
      .exchange()
      .doOnSuccess(success)
      .doOnError(error);
}

send(cr -> processResponse(cr), ex -> processException(ex));
```

Note however that `exchange()` is now deprecated - you'd now normally use `exchangeToMono()` instead, supplying a function that returns a `Mono<Foo>` from the client response. (If you really want to just return a `Mono<ClientResponse>` as before, you could just do `.exchangeToMono(Mono::just)` instead though.)